# Passing string arguments into functions via for loops

Tags: r, arguments, trim, zoo

I'm having issues passing string type arguments into functions.  For example:

```
    date.range <- seq.Date(from=as.Date('2011-01-01'), 
                           to=as.Date('2011-12-31'), by='1 day')
    a.zoo<-zoo(1:365,date.range); 
    b.zoo<-zoo(2:366, date.range); 
    c.zoo<-zoo(3:367, date.range)
    zooNames<-c("a.zoo", "b.zoo", "c.zoo")
    for(name in zooNames){
        aggind.day<-format(index(name), '%Y-%m-%d')
        name.stitch<-str_c(name,'.avg')
        name.stitch<-aggregate(coredata(name), aggind.day, mean)
    }
    rm(a.zoo, b.zoo, c.zoo, zooNames, name, name.stitch, aggind.day)
```

Returns the error: invalid 'trim' argument.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do?  maybe `eval(parse(text=name))` is what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that a few `get`s will help, but I agree with Justin that you need to tell us what you're trying to do. e.g. you assign a string to `name.stitch` then immediately try to overwrite it with _something_ (but it's not clear to me what you want that `aggregate` statement to do).

Comment: Also, the `by` argument in `aggregate` needs to be a list, so you'll need to do `list(aggind.day)`.

Comment: @joran, I don't think that is true. I think the OP intends to use `aggregate.zoo`

Comment: of course it's all speculation since `coredata(name)` will give something like "a.zoo"

Comment: @GSee That might be what the OP intends, but as written, passing `coredata()` to `aggregate` suggests that the zoo method won't be dispatched. But you're right, perhaps they don't really mean to use `coredata`. Who knows? :)

Comment: The purpose of the code is to get the daily average of multiple zoo objects.  I would also re-name each new zoo object in the middle of the loop.  The aggind.day gives the index for aggregating the coredata of each zoo object.  Hope this helps clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error thrown that you are trying to apply `format` function with`trim` argument assigned to `character` type value, namely `%Y-%m-%d`. However `trim` should be of `boolean` type, i.e. code:

```
format(1, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

throws:

> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width,
>   3L,  :    invalid 'trim' argument

You can use `get` and `assign` function to get and set variables. Please see the code below. The algorithm below calculates averaged data for the week day during a year. For the weekday identification `lubridate` package `wday` function was used.

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
date.range <- seq.Date(from=as.Date('2011-01-01'), 
                       to=as.Date('2011-12-31'), by='1 day')
a.zoo <- zoo(1:365,date.range); 
b.zoo <- zoo(2:366, date.range); 
c.zoo <- zoo(3:367, date.range)
zooNames <- c("a.zoo", "b.zoo", "c.zoo")

for(name in zooNames){
  z <- get(name)
  w_days <- wday(date.range, label = TRUE, locale = "English_United States")
  agg  <- aggregate(z, w_days, mean)
  assign(paste0(name, ".avg"), agg)
}

a.zoo.avg
b.zoo.avg
c.zoo.avg
```

Output:

```
> a.zoo.avg
  Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat 
180.5 181.5 182.5 183.5 184.5 185.5 183.0 
> a.zoo.avg
  Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat 
180.5 181.5 182.5 183.5 184.5 185.5 183.0 
> b.zoo.avg
  Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat 
181.5 182.5 183.5 184.5 185.5 186.5 184.0 
> c.zoo.avg
  Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat 
182.5 183.5 184.5 185.5 186.5 187.5 185.0
```